# How to pass Python string to C++ (extern C) function

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have q.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {

int isNExist (std::string* sequence) {
    std::cout << sequence << std::endl;
    // here I want to process input string and return some int value
    return 0;
}

}
```

q.py

```
from ctypes import cdll, c_char_p, c_int

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('mylib.so')

lib.isNExist.restype = c_int
lib.isNExist.argtypes = [c_char_p]
string = "Hello world!".encode("UTF-8")
lib.isNExist(string)
```

open cmd:

```
g++ -c -fPIC q.cpp -o q.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,mylib.so -o mylib.so  q.o
```

And when I run (32-bit) `python q.py` it returns me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "q.py", line 27, in <module>
print(lib.isNExist(string))
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x43544741
```

How should I pass value correctly to C++ (C in this case as I use extern C) function to use it?

**EDIT:**

I edited my code a little and tried char instead of string:

q.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {

int isNExist (char* sequence) {
    std::cout << sequence << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

}
```

q.py

```
from ctypes import cdll, c_char_p, c_char, c_float, c_int,c_wchar_p, POINTER

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('mylib.so')


# send strings to c function
lib.isNExist.argtypes = [POINTER(c_char_p)]
lib.isNExist.restype = c_int
s = "Hello world!".encode("UTF-8")
string_length = len(s)
string_type = c_char_p*string_length
#print(string_type)
result = lib.isNExist(string_type(*s))
```

and it pass and prints only the first character ('H'), but I want to pass full string. What should I do?

**EDIT 2:**

In cpp if I pass string in isNEsixt function it will print whole string correctly and `string_type` is `<class '__main__.c_char_p_Array_12'>`, so I assume that I missing something in result row in Python code

Answer (score 0):

`q.cpp` file should stay as it is for my example. Comments are written in the python code

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {

int isNExist (char* sequence) {
    std::cout << sequence << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`q.py`

```
from ctypes import cdll, c_char_p, c_char, c_float, c_int,c_wchar_p,addressof, create_string_buffer,POINTER

# connect to .so
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('mylib.so')

# set data types of arguments of cpp function
lib.isNExist.argtypes = [c_char_p]

# set result data type
lib.isNExist.restype = c_int

# string I want to pass to the function
s = "Hello world!".encode("UTF-8")

# create buffer that will pass my string to cpp function
buff = create_string_buffer(s)

# passing buff to function
result = lib.isNExist(buff)
```